# Best way to switch between two colours with javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

Javascript beginner here. I essentially want to make a simple switch. If an element is black, change it to white. If it is white, change it to black.

```js
function changeClass() {
    if (document.getElementById('myButton').style.backgroundColor == "white") {
        document.getElementById('myButton').style.backgroundColor = "black";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('myButton').style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }
}
```

```html
<button class="normal" id="myButton" onclick='changeClass()' >Change Colour</button>
```

This code is quite messy though. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

Toggle a class:

```
function changeClass(){
  document.getElementById('myButton').classList.toggle("the-class");
}
```

where your CSS is:

```
.the-class {
    background-color: black;
}
```

...assuming the element's normal background color is white.

More about `classList` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList). Support is good, but you may need a polyfill in older environments.

**Example:**

```js
function changeClass() {
  document.getElementById('myButton').classList.toggle("the-class");
}
```

```css
.the-class {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<button class="normal" id="myButton" onclick='changeClass()'>Change Colour</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `classList.toggle()`

```js
document.querySelector('#myButton').addEventListener('click',e => {
  e.target.classList.toggle('black')

})
```

```css
.black{
  background:black
}
```

```html
<button class="normal" id="myButton">Change Colour</button>
```

Comment: Would accept this one, as it also details how to remove that onclick from the HTML which is good as linking JS to HTML directly is generally considered bad practice.

Answer (score 2):

Use something like `classList.toggle()`

```js
function switchColor(){
  document.getElementById("resultDiv").classList.toggle("toggle")
}
```

```css
.element {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.element.toggle{
  background-color: blue !important;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="switchColor()">Click me</button>
<div id="resultDiv" class="element toggle"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create some specific class in your css (say, `.black` class which contains a `background-color: black;` rule) and then attach/detach that class based on your condition.

Your DOM element (HTML tag) have a handy `classList` property, which can be treated as a list of classes attached to this DOM. I suggest to read a bit more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_classlist.asp).

Overall, your function can be written like:

```
  const element = document.getElementById("coolDiv");
  element.classList.contains('black')) {
    element.classList.remove('black')
  } else {
    element.classList.add('black')
  }
```

or even a little more concise with a ternary operator

```
  const element = document.getElementById("coolDiv");
  element.classList.contains('black') ?
    element.classList.remove('black') : element.classList.add('black')
```

or just with a `toggle` function of the same `classList` property

```
  const element = document.getElementById("coolDiv");
  element.classList.toggle('black')
```

Hope it helps! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

and if white it's not the defualt color you can refactor using ? operator:

```
let btn = document.getElementById('myButton');
btn.style.backgroundColor = btn.style.backgroundColor === 'white' ? 'black' : 'white';
```

Answer (score 0):

For this action not needed external javascript you can write simple inline javascript here the code:

```css
.black-button { 
  background: black; 
  color: #fff; 
  outline: 0;
  padding: 20px;
}
button {
  transition: 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button class="normal" onclick="this.classList.toggle('black-button')">Change Colour</button>
```