# Change any new incoming elements in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I have written a function to change the colour of some text when I click a button.

It works, but the server can receive new text while it is active - it is a chat app. The new text that it receives is in the old colour, not the new one which should be set by the button

```
 function changeClass(){
var myElements = document.querySelectorAll(".from-chat p");
      for (var i = 0; i < myElements.length; i++) {
        myElements[i].style.color = "black";
        myElements[i].style.backgroundColor = "orange";
      }
}
```

Is there any way I can change this to dynamically set all new text that is received to the server to this colour?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not use CSS?

Comment: Change it while appending the new text?

Comment: You just got an answer here showing how you should change a class instead, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56110588/ Combine that with using the _descendant combinator_ in the selector to apply your formatting, then you only need to change the class on one single element, and it will automatically apply to “new” elements that match the selector.

Comment: You can chage the class of cointaining element of all text messages to reflect the choosed color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that easily through css instead of js, like:

```
.from-chat p{
  color:black;
  backgroundColor:orange;
}
```